# Issue with installing Keras library from Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, theano

I have been trying to install 'Keras' library from Anaconda on my laptop. I have the latest version of Anaconda. After that, I tried

> conda update conda
>
> conda update --all

The above two succeeds. After that I tried

> conda install -c conda-forge keras
>
> conda install keras

Both of the above fails with the below error.

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package >'::automat-0.7.0-py_1'.
>   CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. >C:\Users\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

I downloaded "automat-0.7.0-py_1" from anaconda site into one local folder and tried conda install from there. It works. However when I try to install Keras again, that again fails. I am clueless now what to do.

Comment: I am having this problem too...will post if I figure it out

Comment: Newest version of Tensorflow includes Keras as the high API. Why don't you try to install tf?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved using:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

Or, if conda <=4.3:

```
conda update -n root conda
```

I see that other users solved with

```
conda config --add pinned_packages defaults::conda
```

and

```
conda clean --all --yes
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that tensorflow is not yet released for Python3.7 (you have mentioned latest version of Anaconda). To overcome this, you may create a new environment with Python3.6 and simultaneously install Keras.

`conda create -n p360 python=3.6 anaconda tensorflow keras`

Here p360 is the name of the environment I chose.